# Progress bar on centre in relative layout

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@drawable/stalker_background"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >


<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"      
    />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/svProfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/VPSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
            />


            <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                    <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>       

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Progress Bar appears at corner of the screen, how can I align it on centre of the screen. I have relative layout and I'm removing this progress bar after I have some thing to show on screen that's why I need this on top of other controls.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this..

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `ProgressBar` because you parent layout is `RelativeLayout`

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"      
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong, I have added more code in my question. I want progress bar to be in the centre of viewPager

Comment: @Yawar Then give the `ProgressBar` inside `ViewPager` content layouts.

Comment: Done this, But it doesn't show up. May be it is at the back of viewpager. How can I bring it on top of viewPager if it is under it.?

Comment: @Yawar No No i am telling put `ProgressBar` inside `ViewPager` 1st item layout.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/stalker_background"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/svProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```